# RedirectMatch 301 in urls.py for Django

Tags: django, django-urls

Since Django does not do .htaccess (at least on my host), I need to do a 301 RedirectMatch in the similar manner that you'd do an .htaccess RedirectMatch:

`RedirectMatch 301 ^/oldfolder/(.*)$ http://sub.domain.com/newfolder/$1`

The wildcard does not work in the same manner that it does for the .htaccess, so any help appreciated! It must be a permanent redirect too so that search indexes will know it got moved. What am I  redirecting is images to my new CDN subdomain.

Answer (score 2):

Not tested:

```
# Django >= 1.3
from Django.views.generic.base import RedirectView


urls = patterns('', 
   # some patterns here...

   url(
       r"^oldfolder/(?P<whatever>.*)$",
       RedirectView.as_view(
          url="http://sub.domain.com/newfolder/%(whatever)s",
          )
      ),

   # more patterns here
  )
```

[edit] Re-reading your question: "What am I redirecting is images to my new CDN subdomain" - if that's about static medias (images, css etc) then they shouldn't be served by Django but by your front web server (Apache, Nginx, whatever) so assuming Apache you can use a simple `RedirectMatch` in your vhost config.